# Location manager is not calling onlocationchanged method

Tags: android, google-maps

LocationManager is not able to call onLocationChanged  because of which I am not able to get the current location. got the api key, provided the package name and SHA1 key, provided all the dependencies, applied all method still the output is just this map all the time. Is there any problem with the physical device i am using.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {




private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    locationManager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            LatLng myplace = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myplace).title("veraval").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                    defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myplace,20));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    } else {


        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }



}
```

This is the output I am getting without marker in the map, is there any problem with the api key or anything with the code

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in MapReady...

```
 googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext()).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
 googleApiClient.connect();
```

Hope it helps.